# Cannot find resource MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Couldn't find an answer that worked so I'm asking this question again. I am using Visual Studio with MVC5 and Entity Framework to send a form. My problem is whenever I try to access the form I get an error 'cannot find resource' (it's in French on my screen, I hope that's the correct translation). 
Here's my architecture:

MonLivredor/Controllers/HomeController.cs

MonLivredor/View/Home/Formulaire.cshtml

Here is the method I use in the controller to get the posted data from the form:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Formulaire()
    {

        String nom = Request.Form["nom"];
        String mail = Request.Form["mail"];
        String message = Request.Form["message"];

        Commentaire com = new Commentaire(nom, mail, message);
        context.Liste.Add(com);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return View(context);

    }
```

And finally my Form which I try to launch manually in VS 2015:

```
<h2>Formulaire</h2>
<form method="post" action="/Home/Formulaire">
    <h2>Nom</h2>
    <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom"/>
    <h2>Mail</h2>
    <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail"/>
    <h2>Message</h2>
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message"/>
</form>
```

Just in case that could help, here is my global.asax.cs without any modifications:

```
namespace MonLivredor
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the model Commentaire.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MonLivredor.Models
{
    public class Commentaire 
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String Nom { get; set; }
        public String Mail { get; set; }
        public String Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public Commentaire(String nom, String mail, String message)
        {
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            this.Nom = nom;
            this.Mail = mail;
            this.Message = message;
        }

        public Commentaire()
        {
        }


    }
}
```

Sorry for the redundant subject, I couldn't find anything that works. I've tried changing my routing but it didn't seem to help either.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is the Model expected by the _Formulaire.cshtml_ View?

Comment: It's called Commentaire.cs I'll add it

Answer (score 0):

You should use tag name="" in your form, like that:

```
<h2>Formulaire</h2>
<form method="post" action="/Home/Formulaire">
    <h2>Nom</h2>
    <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom"/>
    <h2>Mail</h2>
    <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail"/>
    <h2>Message</h2>
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message"/>
</form>
```

and better way for your method is using a ModelBinder:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Formulaire(Commentaire com)
    {

        context.Liste.Add(com);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return View(context);

    }
```

and mvc framework subsidiary methods for your form:

```
    <h2>Formulaire</h2>
    @using (Html.Beginform("Formulaire","Home"))
{ 
        <h2>Nom</h2>
        @Html.Editor("nom")
        <h2>Mail</h2>
        @Html.Editor("mail")
        <h2>Message</h2>
        @Html.Editor("message")

}
```